# Why is a conservatory called that?

Tags: etymology

Conservatory is defined as greenhouse, glass house, or hothouse. Where does this meaning come from?

Comment: You need to show your research before asking; “*The word conservatory is derived from the Italian “conservato” (stored or preserved) and Latin “ory” – a place for – and was originally used to describe a non–glazed structure used for storing food. Later the word was used to describe glazed structures for conserving, or protecting, plants from cold weather.”* (Wikipedia)

Comment: How about 'music conservatory'? That's weird.

Comment: For musical sense, see https://www.etymonline.com/word/conservatory#etymonline_v_18237

Comment: @Graffito If the question gets reopened, that sounds like an answer!

Comment: 'Please include the research you’ve done ... Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.' The person/s voting to re-open are openly rejecting this requirement which has long marked ELU as a credible resource.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ..and the SE platform as a whole: some basic research is required almost everywhere. Revoted to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conservatories were introduced From Holland by William of Orange at the end of the 17th century, the first greenhouses being inspired by Amsterdam Hortus botanicus created in 1638.

The objective was to hold a vast collection of plants from all over the word and maintain them in a good state of health, i.e. their "conservation" (the act of preventing something from being lost, wasted, damaged, or destroyed).

The sense of this term has perhaps evolved over the time. In French, it's quite a synonym of preservation (keep sth in proper condition).